# Can I change the toolbar color of default gallery by opening gallery from my application using Intent?

Tags: android, camera, gallery, toolbar

I want to change the toolbar color of default gallery application by opening intent from my application. In IOS it can be done. But i can not find any option to do it in android platform.

Answer (score 0):

According to Google, there are ~24,000 Android device models. There is no single "default gallery application" — there are dozens, if not hundreds, of such applications.

You have no way to control what color they use for their action bar. You do not even know if they *have* an action bar.